# SSO - Ms Graph and Storage Access

Tags: azure-blob-storage, single-sign-on, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently looking for a SSO solution to access MS Graph and Storage Accounts with a signle interactive user login. When I connect via Connect-AzAccount and grab the token via Get-AzAccessToken it will cut all the required scopes (intune administrator scopes)

Connect-AzAccount
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph).token

## connects sucessfully but failes when running query below

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token

$GraphURI="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/?$filter=contains(displayName, '7-Zip - 19.00')"

## FAILES no scopes

$GraphResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GraphURI -Method "GET" -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose:$false

When I try to other way around (connect via graph and grab the token) those wont match
[Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult]$AccessTokenGraph != [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAccessToken] $AccessTokenAzAccount

Is there a way to do it? Its important that its done via an interactive login and not via a certficate or app registration.

Thank you!
Eli

Answer (score 1):

**Note** that : **`Connect-AzAccount`** authenticates the user with Azure and this authenticated account can be used only with Azure Resource Manager requests and **`Connect-MgGraph`** allows the connection to Microsoft Graph.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

When I tried to connect to Mg Graph by using the access token generated by `Get-AzAccessToken` I got the error as below:

```
Connect-AzAccount $token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph).token

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token
$GraphURI="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps
$GraphResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GraphURI -Method "GET" -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose:$false
```

[image]

[image]

Based on your requirement it is not feasible to have a single interactive user login to access both MS Graph and Storage Accounts. You have to connect `AzAccount` and `MgGraph` once at a time as access token of both varies.

You can connect to MgGraph in several ways, and **I am able to fetch the details of deviceAppManagement successfully** like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Using Microsoft Graph PowerShell authentication commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/authentication-commands?view=graph-powershell-1.0#delegated-access)

Comment: thank you for looking into this! 

The thing is...I am doing the same thing with a managed identity in a runbook inside of the azure environment and it seems to run just fine. I can fire the rest queries and all the permissions are in the scope of the token.

Comment: What I dont understand is why the user is treated differently than the managed identiy. I literally grab the token in the exact same way ($Global:AccessToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph) and it works like a charm.